# Need to understand why measures converging to a set function gives a measure

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, self-learning

Consider the following theorem and its proof.[image]

I do not understand the claim that for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ there exists a a measure  $\nu_n$ such that $\mu_n = \mu_{n-1} + \nu_n$. Could someone please explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\nu_n(A) = \mu_n(A)-\mu_{n-1}(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal S$.  For general measures, this difference would perhaps be a signed measure.  But from the assumption $\mu_n \uparrow$ it is nonnegative.

There may be a question about $\infty - \infty$.  It doesn't matter, say take it to be $\infty$.